# How to hide a div on second click with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

I have this little script which shows my div on the first click, but I want it to hide if it is clicked again!

Do I have my `if...else` statement wrong?

```
<a onClick='view()'>OTHER HTML CONTENT</a>
<div id="a" class="superHide"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/iagLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/TelstraLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/FootballFedAus_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/pngLng_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/NRMA_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BupaLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" /></div>

<script>
function view() {
var testMe=document.getElementById('a').getAttribute('display');
  if(testMe=='block'){
        document.getElementById('a').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
  } else{
        document.getElementById('a').setAttribute('style', 'display:block');
  }
}
</script>

.superHide {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: You don't. Are you really trying to use Java?

Comment: Note: the `<img>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash in HTML and never has.

Comment: I have shown the reason you cannot see the `<div>` tag

Answer (score 0):

When getting attributes, you want to reference the `style` property on the DOM element directly rather that try to use the getter. I believe the getter only works if the style is set inline directly on the HTML. If the style is set through CSS, it will be contained only on that prop. Your getter was always returning null. Since null == 'block' returns false, the display block was always ran. Something like this will work:

```
function view() {
  var target = document.getElementById('a');
  var shown = target.style.display === 'block;
  target.setAttribute('style', `display:${shown ? 'none' : 'block'}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, I copied your HTML and applied the JS to do as you need.
You'll notice the `onClick='view(this, "a")'` provides the element to the function

```
<a onClick='view(this, "a")'>OTHER HTML CONTENT</a>
<div id="a" class="superHide"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/iagLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/TelstraLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/FootballFedAus_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/pngLng_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/NRMA_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BupaLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" /></div>


function view(item, targetId) {
    if(item.dataset.clickCount == undefined) { item.dataset.clickCount = 0 }
    item.dataset.clickCount = Number(item.dataset.clickCount) + 1

    let displayFormat = ['block', 'none'][item.dataset.clickCount % 2]
    let displayStyle = `display:${displayFormat}`

    document.getElementById(targetId).setAttribute('style', displayStyle);
}

</script>
```

I dig your raw flavour so I continued using the builtin functionality.

The trick here is the modulo (modulus) flip on the counter setup within the element.
First I applied a counter to the `dataset` on the element, Then increment `clickCount` on every click. The `dataset` naturally stores as a String type, so I convert it to make sure the math increments.

Then using the modulo `% 2`, the click count flips between `0` and `1`. This allows a cleaner string and saves repetition.

For one last trick, provide the *target* node ID from the click item. Now this function will on any clicky item against any target without code changes.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your Image is not visible i.e: Image you used is not correct.

So please use correct Image and use below script to get your result.

It seems your image is not being shown here.

so Even according your question below script will work fine.

But the problem is actually different. Your images are not being loaded.

I have attached the reason why your images are not being shown in here.

[image: Reason your images not loading]

```js
function view() {
var testMe=document.getElementById('a').style.display;
console.log(testMe);
  if(testMe=='none' || testMe == ''){
        document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'block';
  } else{
        document.getElementById('a').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```css
.superHide {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<a onClick='view()'>OTHER HTML CONTENT</a>
<div id="a" class="superHide"><img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/iagLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/TelstraLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/FootballFedAus_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/pngLng_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/NRMA_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" />
<img class="alignnone size-full wp-image-940 imgWrap" src="http://boxingclever.net.au/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/BupaLogo_300px.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="125" /></div>
```